ros-noetic-desktop-full installation problem UBUNTU 20.04 focal
I have just started learning ROS, and when I tried to follow the official installation guide I encountered the following problem:

Here is Software & Updates settings


Here is the output of apt-cache search ros-noetic show?

And also output of sudo apt-get update


Following Tully's advice I run sudo apt install -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=1 ros-noetic-roscpp and get a list of errors, the only thing I could make of it is that it has something to do with amd64. Error log: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q7uize08ZlCKgjESd-B5xaO9D6qKe8zz/view?usp=sharing

try the usual with broken packages: sudo apt install -f

Please copy and paste the text from your console instead of screenshotting. That way it's searchable and selectable which makes it much easier to help you.

Please keep drilling down to the minimal command and error trace. And then you can embed it here in the question.

I'm seeing errors related to python3-setuptools and uuid-dev do you have any non-standard packages installed on your system? And are you up to date with an apt-get dist-upgrade?

You likely have a package that conflicts on your system or a package that is pinned or conflicts in another way. To find out more information about what the problem is you should use
-o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=1  with your apt install aka:
sudo apt-get install -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=1 ros-noetic-desktop-full
You can also reduce the problem set by trying to install the dependent packages until you drill down to find the specific conflict.
More info on apt options can be found at: https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/apt/apt.conf.5.en.html or man apt.conf

Thanks, I added an error log in the main post.

Thanks, that output is extremely long. Can you please narrow down exactly what package is causing the problem by attempting to install individual dependencies to get a reduced traceback? Have you installed any ROS packages before such as upstream ones that might conflict? https://wiki.ros.org/UpstreamPackages

I run installation of ros-noetic-roscpp and get a much shorter error log, hopefully it's readable now. And I have never installed any  kind of upstream ROS packages before. Thank you for your help.

Thank you everyone for help! In the end, I decided to reinstall Linux and now everything works perfectly.
